# Сменить видео js с по подходящему условию if

Tags: javascript, json, видео

Возник вопрос, как сменить видео которое производится бекграунд. Есть 5 возможных вариантов, и при каждом варианте должно отображаться свое видео.
Часть кода с Html:

```
<body>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source type="video/mp4" class="videoWeather" src = video/clear.mp4>
    </video>
```

и JS
получаю значение погоды, и при условиях должно показываться свое видео и картинка. Картинка меняется, видео остается неизменимым

```
 let backgroundVideo = document.querySelector(".videoWeather");

    meteorSituation = json.weather[0].main;
    
                console.log(meteorSituation);
    
                // meteorSituation = "Snow"
    
                if (meteorSituation === "Clear") {
                    backgoundImg.src = ` `;
                    backgroundVideo.src = `video/clear.mp4`;
                    backgoundImg.src = `img/Clear.png`;
                }
                if (meteorSituation === "Clouds") {
                    backgoundImg.src = ` `;
                    backgroundVideo.src = ` `;
                    backgroundVideo.src = `video/clouds.mp4`;
                    backgoundImg.src = `img/Clouds.png`;
                }
```

Comment: backgroundVideo.load()

Comment: можно подробнее?

Comment: Надо сказать вашему плееру - перегрузись )  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732562/can-i-use-javascript-to-dynamically-change-a-videos-source]()

Comment: но загрузка информации идет с сервера, а видео на компе. если эту операцию делать при проверке сервера ошибка: main.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: backgroundVideo.load is not a function
Если принудительно при нажатии на ентер - Uncaught TypeError: backgroundVideo.load is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.nameCity

Comment: document.getElementById("myVideo").load().  Упустил, что backgroundVideo это другой элемент

Comment: Большое спасибо!  сделал : myVideo.load();  нужно делать было именно на video(html) а не  на source.   Возможно в будущем Ваш ответ пригодится и другим новичкам))